# openmpi and intel icc icpc

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, openmpi, icc

Deal all;

I want to make openmpi 1.10.2 with intel icc and icpc in ubuntu 14.04 x64, so first I installed intel compliers, to check this:

```
$ icc -v

$ icc version 13.1.0 (gcc version 4.7.0 compatibility)

$ icpc -v

$ icpc version 13.1.0 (gcc version 4.7.0 compatibility)

$ which icc

$ /opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.2.146/bin/intel64/icc

$ which icpc

$ /opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.2.146/bin/intel64/icpc

after these, in openmpi directory:

$ ./configure --prefix=/usr/local CC=icc CXX=icpc

... output of configure ...

$ sudo make

... output of make ...

$ sudo make install

/home/riza/openmpi-1.10.2/libtool: line 8979: icc: command not found
libtool: install: error: relink `libopen-rte.la' with the above command before installing it
make[3]: *** [install-libLTLIBRARIES] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/riza/openmpi-1.10.2/orte'
make[2]: *** [install-am] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/riza/openmpi-1.10.2/orte'
make[1]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/riza/openmpi-1.10.2/orte'
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
```

could you please help me?

Reza

Answer (score 1):

Because `libtool` can't find where `icc` and `icpc` are, so you should provide exact link to them. In your case, try:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local CC=/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.2.146/bin/intel64/icc CXX=/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.2.146/bin/intel64/icpc
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your root account doesn't have the same environment pointers to Intel Composer.  Try installing without sudo with --prefix somewhere where you own (or can comfortably own) the directory and make symlinks to /usr/local.